# What is the difference between `warSourceExcludes` and `packagingExcludes` in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

The Maven WAR plugin has two configuration options: `warSourceExcludes` and `packagingExcludes`. There is some documentation on [`packagingExcludes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html), saying that:

> It is possible to include or exclude certain files from the WAR file, by using the `<packagingIncludes>` and `<packagingExcludes>` configuration parameters.

However, I find it very difficult to find information on `warSourceExcludes`.

What is the difference between these two configuration options?

I'm using Maven 3.1.1 and the WAR plugin is version 2.4

Comment: Which version of maven are you using?

Comment: I am using Maven 3.1.1 and the WAR plugin is version 2.4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> warSourceExcludes: The comma separated list of tokens to exclude
>   when copying the content of the warSourceDirectory.

---

> packagingExcludes: The comma separated list of tokens to exclude
>   from the WAR before packaging.

With packagingExcludes, the tokens are completely excluded from the final war file.

With warSourceExcludes, the tokens are just ignored when copying the war directory into the war file.

As a result, if the tokens are present in the webappDirectory for example, they will not be ignored when using warSourceExcludes but will be when usingpackagingExcludes.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignored when copying"??? If they are not copied to the war file - they are not packaged in the war file, and it's the same as packagingExcludes. Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: the example at the end of the paragraph should've clarified.

Comment: No. It doesn't make any sense. I have tried the same filter (e.g. `index*`) with `packagingExcludes`, and then only with `warSourceExcludes`. The resulting war file is the same - index.jsp is not in a generated war file. A temporary folder (target/asdf) is different, but does it matter?

Comment: I agree. It makes no sense. The answer of ryenus should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

The process of producing the final war file can be simplified as two major steps:

1. the web resources are copied from `${warSourceDirectory}` into `${<webappDirectory>}`, let's say it's `target/artifact/`, which can be treated like:

   ```sh
   cp -r src/main/webapp/* target/artifact/
   ```

   `<warSourceExcludes>` is used at this step, so that the excluded files are NOT copied into `target/artifact/`.
2. the output directory `target/artifact` of the above step, namely `${webappDirectory}`, is then used as the input to produce the final war file, like:

   ```sh
   jar --create --file target/artifact.war -C target/artifact/ WEB-INF ...
   ```

   And here `<packagingExcludes>` is used, deciding what to pack up from `target/artifact/`.

see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, the correct answer has already been provided by 'ryenus' above.

I am merely documenting an example how 'warSourceExcludes' is used in a pom as [the maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceExcludes) is very sketchy and there are not many questions related to this.

I have used the 'warSourceExcludes' in situation where the web app is bundled by npm (with node)/webpack and therefore generated 'node' and 'node_modules' folders in the webapp directory (refer: [Maven Frontend Plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)).

During the war overlay process (copying from webapp to target folder), by default, the node and node_modules were copied in the /target/app-name directory and then with 'packagingExcludes' option was excluded from the generated WAR.

This worked, however, the WAR build time was excessive as node and especially node_modules directory is very large in size, the copying time is high.

The solution was not to copy the node and node_modules to the /target/app-name directory. This was achieved by using the 'warSourceExcludes'.

[image]